# como enviar 44000 datos por nodemcu(esp8266)?

Tags: java, lua

Mi problema es a la hora de hacer el envió se reinicia el módulo. Al parecer el buffer se llena con 1460 datos es necesario encontrar la manera de enviar 44000
la conexión que estoy utilizando es UDP. **¿Cómo puedo aumentar la cantidad de datos que envío?**

Comment: si bien udp puede transportar hasta 65,527 bytes, no es aconsejable enviar paquetes tan grandes. las redes ip pueden tranquilamente descartar el paquete sin aviso. lo mejor seria que mandes muchos paquetes pequeños, que son mas faciles de entregar y llevar una lista de los paquetes recibidos del otros lado. no es simple pero lo digo por experiencia, es pereferble eso, o si puedes cambiarte a TCP es mejor pues te evitas todo ese desarrollo.

Comment: cerradores: esta claro lo que se pregunta, si no sabe presione el boton "omitir".